# Get an enumerable range for a given min and max with a given number of steps

Tags: c#, winforms, range

I am familiar with the [Enumerable.Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method for generating an enumeration of values.  But I would like something slightly different.  I want to provide a min value, max value, and a number of desired points.

**IE:**

`Method(double min, double max, int numberOfSteps)`

taking

`Method(0, 1000, 11);`

would return

`0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000`

I figure for something like this, there must be a built-in method but my search hasn't turned anything up.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Other than the fact that you want the values to be `double`, everything else can be done with `Enumerable.Range`. I don't think there's anything built-in to do what you want, but it's trivial to implement on top of `Enumerable.Range`:

```
return Enumerable.Range(0, steps)
                 .Select(i => min + (max - min) * ((double)i / (steps - 1)));
```

I've written that somewhat carefully so that you always end up with the final value. It does bork if you say you only want a single step though... you might want to guard against that and use `Enumerable.Repeat(min, 1)` in that case.

Comment: Wow that's really simple and clever.  Thanks.  And I'll do exactly that regarding an input of 1 step.  Actually negative steps as well.  Something like `if (steps <= 1) return Enumerable.Repeat(min, 1);`

Comment: what if you want the values to be double ?

Comment: Hell... I wanted to use this method to setup test data... Now I need a test method to assert a testdata method... :-)

Answer (score 3):

Just calculate **'Common Difference'** & generate the series:

**d = (max - min)/(numberOfSteps - 1)**

Now, You can easily generate your series:

```
int [] a = new [numberOfSteps];

for(i=0; i<numberOfSteps ; i++)
{
  a[i] = min + (numberOfSteps - 1)d;
}
```