# Python : numpy.arange equivalent function with min, max, and 'number of bins' instead of 'steps'?

Tags: python, numpy, range

I am looking for the Python equivalent of this : [Get an enumerable range for a given min and max with a given number of steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408118/get-an-enumerable-range-for-a-given-min-and-max-with-a-given-number-of-steps) and I am surprised I can not find an easy answer to this.

If I want a range from 0 to 1, with steps of 0.001, I simply compute :

```
my_range = np.arange(0, 1, 0.001)
```

What I am looking for is a simple range function where the user defines the number of bins, not the step size, like :

```
my_range = function(0, 1, cut_into = 1000)
```

I could do it manually with :

```
start = 0
end = 1
cut_into = 1000
my_range = np.arange(start, end, (end-start)/cut_into)
```

but I would like to avoid computing this as it looks overkill

Comment: Try np.linspace(0,1,1000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `function` to [`np.linspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) :)

```
np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)
```

Comment: As simple as that